# How to move an item out of a group using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: sketch-app

Using option + command + arrow down doesn't move it out of a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In Illustrator

Select the item,

- Then *cut* <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,
- Deselect all with <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,
- Then paste it in place with <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

  ---

### In Sketch

Just replace deselect all with <kbd>Esc</kbd> and do a regular paste.

---

It may be one step more but it works and it's all key shortcuts :)